# Do you know any nice interface for C# Interactive standalone?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, shell, read-eval-print-loop, c#-interactive

You can open the C# Interactive window in Visual Studio to use C# as a scripting an shell language. Unfortunately, this requires you to have Visual Studio open all the time.

I know I can run csi.exe itself, but this does not give me any syntax highlighting or auto completion features.

How can I run the C# Interactive Windows standalone?

Comment: Powershell ISE comes close. You are trying to build Visual Studio without wanting to call it Visual Studio.

Comment: Youre going to get bombarded with opinions on this one

Comment: What I wish IS Visual Studio - actually, without the main window overload. I need a command line like `ide.exe /csi`. This has not yet been invented?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest LINQPad (I don't use it myself but I know this can do that kind of things). I think it's pretty powerful

https://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: Looks somehow overloaded to my purpose. However thank you.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode has built in support for .NET Interactive Notebooks - if you don't see it, you can install the '.NET Interactive Notebooks' extension